# Run parallel command and redirect the output to files with specific name

Tags: io-redirection, gnu-parallel

I can't undestand well how the parallel command works.

I need to run this simple command: (100 times)

```
curl https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
curl https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2
curl https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3
...
curl https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/100
```

end redirect the output to files with the names like these:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
....
100.txt
```

Comment: Unless you are really trying to figure out how to do this with the `parallel` command, this may solve your problem: `for i in {1..100}; do curl "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/$i" > "$i.txt"; done`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is a somewhat over-engineered Bash-solution, but it works and hopefully clarifies the use of the `parallel` command:

```
function xx(){ curl "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/$1" > "$1.txt";}
parallel xx -- {1..100}
```

The first line creates a new "command" or function called `xx` which - when executed - causes the execution of a curl command that has its stdout redirected to a file. The `xx` function takes a single number as its argument; inside the body of the function, it is referred to as `$1', i.e. the first positional parameter.

The second line demonstrates the use of the `parallel` command, which runs `xx` once for (and with) each argument from the list 1, 2, 3, ..., 100 (the list 1 2 3 ... 100 is generated by the shell when it performs brace expansion on `{1..100}`).

NOTE: this answer relates to the `parallel` command in the `moreutils` package on Debian systems, not to the `GNU parallel` command.

Comment: My version of Tollef's `parallel` (in `moreutils`) cannot run `bash` functions. With GNU Parallel I can make it work: `env_parallel xx ::: {1..100}` or `export -f xx; parallel xx ::: {1..100}`.

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
parallel curl https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/{} ">" {}.txt ::: {1..100}
```

Consider spending 20 minutes on reading chapter 1+2 of the GNU Parallel 2018 book (print: http://www.lulu.com/shop/ole-tange/gnu-parallel-2018/paperback/product-23558902.html online: https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014). Your command line will love you for it.

Comment: Your answer triggered me to have a better look at the `GNU parallel` command; thanks for the link to your book. For the unsuspecting Debian users it is probably worth noting that there are two "parallel" commands: one from the `moreutils` package (to which my answer relates), and the one known as `GNU parallel` (to which your answer and book relate). See also this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/917577/how-can-i-install-gnu-parallel-alongside-moreutils-on-ubuntu-debian).